# Здравствуйте, при повторном обращений к функций возникает ошибка UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

при повторном обращений к функций связанного с погодой возинкает такая ошибка:

```
*ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-36' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=UnboundLocalError("local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\12345\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\проекты\telbot\main.py", line 125, in get_weather
    weather = await client.find(message.text)
  File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\python_weather\client.py", line 37, in find
    return await self.http.request(location)
  File "C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\python_weather\rest.py", line 28, in request
    elif resp.status >= 400:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment*
```

кто знает как решить, помогите пожалуйста

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import datetime
from random import randint
import requests
import python_weather

dp = Dispatcher(bot)
client = python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL, locale="ru-RU")

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == " Рандомное число")
async def random(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(str(randint(0, 100)))

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "❄ Погода")
async def locat(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('напиши название города и я пришлю сводку погоды')
    @dp.message_handler()
    async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
        weather = await client.find(message.text)
        celsius = round((weather.current.temperature - 32) / 1.8)
        curtemp = f"на данный момент в городе {weather.location_name }\n"
        curtemp += f"Температура: {celsius}\n"
        curtemp += f"общее состояние на улице: {weather.current.sky_text}"
        await message.reply(curtemp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал у себя, вроде бы все ок. Немного поменял код, кое-что убрал, оставил только то что требуется для работы этой команды.

```
import xml

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import python_weather
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

client = python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL, locale="ru-RU")


class Weather(StatesGroup):
    weather = State()


@dp.message_handler(text="Погода")
async def location(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('напиши название города и я пришлю сводку погоды')
    await Weather.weather.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Weather.weather)
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
    try:
        weather = await client.find(message.text)
    except xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError as e:
        await message.answer("Такого города нет")
        return
    celsius = round((weather.current.temperature - 32) / 1.8)
    curtemp = f"на данный момент в городе {weather.location_name}\n"
    curtemp += f"Температура: {celsius}\n"
    curtemp += f"общее состояние на улице: {weather.current.sky_text}"
    await message.answer(curtemp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]